# Backend for Angular 4

Tags: angular

I am building a new Angular application using Visual Studio. I need a backend in order to make my data persist and be able to fetch it at will.
I was looking at ASP.NET Core and ASP.NET MVC, and I cannot understand what makes them different. With my limited knowledge with Angular, which backend solution is more practical for me consider?

Comment: This site is not meant to suggest technologies or tools as it is an opinionated matter. Also, we know nothing about your application.

Comment: @MaciejJureczko according to OPs question, I was able to make a lot of assumptions that OP "doesn't know what he's talking about" but also is "willing to learn". Guiding him with the architectural approach is really the answer he is looking for (if I was the OP)

Comment: @Moshe Your suggested edit, while making the question prettier to read, does nothing to make it any less off-topic at Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Tyler sorry man just trying to help

Comment: It was a very good edit, @Moshe, so I approved it before closing, but please do try to focus your editing efforts on questions that are a better fit for [our guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) in the future.

Comment: I feel the OP was asking for guidance on backend, and wasn't really sure what to ask. I asked a similar question like this regarding how to understand how webdev all ties in with the frontend and the server. Nobody really "teaches" you these things, you know @CodyGray?

Comment: This web site may help define the difference between the two: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/choose-aspnet-framework. As others have said, Angular doesn't care as long as the server provides a RESTful or RESTful-like API.

Answer (score 1):

You should use ASP.NET core.

Angular 4 is a backend agnostic, API consuming framework. Therefore the MVC pattern that you are used to with AngularJS is now considered an anti-pattern. In fact, if you consider using ASP.NET or ExpressJS, you'd still be solving the same problem:

You need an API (preferably RESTful) to communicate with your front-end application (Angular), in order to handle authentication, authorization, and persist data to a database (mongodb, postgreSQL, etc) - also known as CRUD.

Consider ASP.NET being just the foundation, and Angular being the brick.
Consider ASP.NET MVC being the foundation and the brick - but you already had a special brick before. Most of the things you would do in ASP.NET MVC can be done in Angular, but some of the things you would do in ASP.NET Core cannot be done with Angular.

What do you need ASP.NET Core for? To hide proprietary or secret formula, function, algorithm. To conceal or encapsulate raw data - and only return the FINALIZED, processed data via JSON.